# loss of precision in calculating derivatives using FFTW3 (FORTRAN)

Tags: fortran, precision, fftw, derivative

The following  code calculates derivative of any sine or cosine trigonometric function using FFTW3 function.

```
program oned

implicit none

include "fftw3.f"

integer, parameter :: nx = 128  
integer :: i
double complex, dimension(0:nx-1) :: input, solution
double precision, dimension(0:nx-1) :: x
double precision, parameter :: pi = acos(-1.0d0), dx = 2.0d0*pi/(nx)
double complex :: wrap_variable, num = (0, 1.0d0)
integer*8 :: plan_x_fwd, plan_x_bwd

call dfftw_plan_dft_1d(plan_x_fwd, nx, input, input, fftw_forward, fftw_measure)
call dfftw_plan_dft_1d(plan_x_bwd, nx, input, input, fftw_backward, fftw_measure)

do i = 0, nx-1                                      
    x(i) = i*dx
    ! function whose derivative is to be calculated.
    input(i) = sin(8*x(i))                              
end do

! call fftw subroutine to calculate fourier coefficients of array
call dfftw_execute_dft(plan_x_fwd, input, input)            

! normalization of array
input = input/nx

do i = 0, nx-1
    if ( i .ge. 0 .and. i .le. nx/2-1 )  then
! calculating first derivatve. This involves multiplying by i*k
! where i**2 = -1 and k is the wavenumber
        input(i) = input(i)*num*i                   
    else if ( i .ge. nx/2 .and. i .le. nx-1) then                   
        input(i) = input(i)*num*(i-nx)                      
    end if                                      
end do

do i = 0, nx-1
    if ( i .gt. 0 .and. i .le. nx/2-1)  then
! calculating second derivative.
        input(i) = input(i)*num*i                       
    else if ( i .ge. nx/2 .and. i .le. nx-1) then   
        input(i) = input(i)*num*(i-nx)
    end if
end do

do i = 0, nx-1
    if ( i .gt. 0 .and. i .le. nx/2-1)  then
! calculating third derivative.
        input(i) = input(i)*num*i                       .
    else if ( i .ge. nx/2 .and. i .le. nx-1) then
        input(i) = input(i)*num*(i-nx)
    end if
end do

input(nx/2) = 0.0d0 

call dfftw_execute_dft(plan_x_bwd, input, input)

! print the error in calculation.
print *, maxval(abs(real(solution - input)))                        

call dfftw_destroy_plan(plan_x_fwd)
call dfftw_destroy_plan(plan_x_bwd)

end program
```

The function I am using as "input" is `sin(8x)`. When I calculate the derivative as above and compare against the answer which is `8*cos(8x)`, I get a maximum error of the order of `E-14`. When I calculate the second derivative and compare against the answer which is `-64*sin(8x)`, then I get an error of the order `E-12`. Similarly for third derivative, I get `E-10`.

I find this very unsettling. I don't see why multiplying the number by `i*k` where `i**2 = -1` and `k` is wavenumber causes precision loss. 
Is this an issue with my code ? Or is it something to do with the nature of floating point numbers and if so why ?

Comment: You are not just multiplying, you are doing FFT two times. That is inherently inexact. If you need more precision, you can try quad instead of the double.